# Amazon spinner probability

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

This problem was asked in the `python` hackathon which I had failed but had taken the screenshot of the problem.

The problem was based on amazon spinner probability;

[image]

- My efforts: The word `and` was my problem I don't know how should I take the word `and` in the problem.
- Confusion: As, there are 6-sections then what did they mean by 'betterlucknexttime'
  how could the probability of `betterlucknext` time be $\frac16$
  I have no idea of probability and statistics but any hint on how I can solve this problem will be helpful to me.

It was a coding question but I wanted to understand the mathematics behind the problem...

Comment: I don't think the question is well stated.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh sorry I couldn't understand? Do you think something is missing?

Comment: The second sentence describe the $7$ sectors and assign $6$ probabilities values, it is confusing to me. If there is a forum for the hackathon or a way to contact the organizer, you might like to ask them.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Exactly, that is the problem the sections are $6$ but what & how the `betterlucknexttime` comes in the picture....

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh What if we think like the probabilities of each even be $\frac 16$ and then apply the conditional probabilities??

Comment: is the hackathon still accessible? can you show us the link? the question has typos. I think the question is very unclear.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Sorry! It's was a week ago it's just I have had taken the screenshot to try in weekends [complete screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXTN5.png)

Comment: Asked and dismissed as flawed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564196/amazon-spinner-probability).

Comment: @BruceET Can you guess the reason? It'll appear on the top when Googled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mentioned that the word 'and' is the bottleneck, so I answer the first part for you.

I interpret the question as out of the $n$ times, we see all the $3$ outcomes appearing at least once. Let the event that the corresponding outcome is observed at least once be $A, B, C$. As the question is badly phrased, I ignore the numerical value and let $p_i$ be the probability that the outcome is $i$ in each spin

The complement to this would be one of the desired outcome does not appear.

\begin{align}
P(A \cap B \cap C) &= 1-P(A^c \cup B^c \cup C^c)\\
&= 1-P(A^c) -P(B^c) - P(C^c) + P(A^cB^c)+P(A^cC^c)+P(B^cC^c)-P(A^cB^cC^c)
\end{align}

We have $P(A^c)=(1-p_A)^n, P(A^cB^c)=(1-p_A-p_B)^n, P(A^cB^cC^c)=(1-p_A-p_B-p_C)^n$. The other values can be computed similarly.

Comment: Thanks I'll mail the organizers on this!

Comment: As, for the second it's `or`  means $P(A \cup B \cup C)$
 \begin{align}
P(A \cup B \cup C) &=  P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(AB)-P(AC)-P(BC)+P(ABC)
\end{align}
Could you please help me provide any thread on the above so that I can read more on that(say proof).....
Actually, The concern is to understand what is $P(ABC)$

Comment: I write $P(AB)$ to mean $P(A \cap B)$. You might like to read on [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle).

Comment: thanks for the thread but don't know why I tried the above problem using `random` module in python (say like the real experiment) but it's not giving even the close answer....
it's giving me $0.47....$

Comment: the question is so badly phrased that i can't even understand the question statement. you might like to consider alternatives such as codeforce, topcoder, atcoder.

Comment: Yeah I understand it's phrase so badly but I wonder how it would look like if we go as to solve the real [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4381017/probability-of-amazon-spinner)