# Probability of amazon spinner

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

[image]

- Find the probability of getting on `Yamaha Guitar`  and `Bose Speaker` and `BetterLuckNext time` is after spinning the spinner in 10 times?
- Fine the probability of getting on `6`  or `20` or `Better Luck next time` is after spinning the spinner in 25 times?
- Find the probability of getting on `Better luck next time is after spinning the spinner in 5 times
- Efforts: [image: Image but don't know if right or wrong]

You can downvote but please don't forget to add comments like Why? if it is too easy don't forget to add your answer.

I mean like Imagine we are trying to get the probability of `Amazon Spinner` isn't that interesting?

Comment: In other words, you want the probability that the spinner lands on each of those events at least once.  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I have been trying for past 6hrs mann nothing concluded over t to this I have discussed with more than 20 people I know but failed about to give up

Comment: @N.F.Taussig https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4380880/amazon-spinner-probability

Comment: The second part of the question is easier.  Simply subtract the probability that none of those three events occurs in $25$ trials from $1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Can you please provide the answer please I'll test if correct then please oblige me with your explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inclusion-exclusion principle, the first quantity should be

\begin{align}
1 - 3\left(\frac56 \right)^{10} + 3\left( \frac46\right)^{10}-\left( \frac12\right)^{10} \approx 0.5685
\end{align}

which agrees with the following simulation

```
from random import randrange

n = 10
trial_number = 100
choices = 6
success_count = 0
for t in range(trial_number):
    A = [0] * choices
    for i in range(n):
        A[randrange(choices)] += 1
    if A[0]*A[1]*A[2] > 0:
        success_count += 1
print(success_count/trial_number)
```

Comment: That's so brilliant!!!!